# How to extract plain text from RTF string using Firebird SQL

Tags: firebird, rtf

I have RTF strings stored in a blob field in my database table. 
Example 1:
The following blob RTF string stores plain text - 'Gluten, oeufs, lait, fruits à coque':

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f1\fnil Tahoma;}}{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang4108\f0\fs16  Gluten, oeufs, lait, fruits \'e0 coque\f1\par}
```

Example 2:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang4108{\fonttbl{\ \fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f1\fnil Tahoma;}}{\*\generator Msftedit 5.41.21.2510;}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs16 Farine de froment, Gruy\'e8re AOP 28%, tomates, mayonnaise (huile de tournesol, oeufs, eau, vinaigre, moutarde, sucre, sel), cornichons (cornichons, vinaigre, sel, sucre, extrait d'\'e9pices, \'e9pices, antioxydant E224), eau, sel, levure, gluten, farine de malt d'orge, \'e9paississant E412, dextrose, \'e9mulsifiant E472e, agent de traitement de la farine E300\f1\par}
```

Stores : 'Farine de froment, Gruyère AOP 28%, tomates, mayonnaise (huile de tournesol, oeufs, eau, vinaigre, moutarde, sucre, sel), cornichons (cornichons, vinaigre, sel, sucre, extrait d'épices, épices, antioxydant E224), eau, sel, levure, gluten, farine de malt d'orge, épaississant E412, dextrose, émulsifiant E472e, agent de traitement de la farine E300'.

How to extract the plain texts from the RTF string?

Comment: Why / where do you want to use that plain text? In the server side (ie in the query's ´where´ clause) on in the client side, program code?

Comment: In the firebird SQL select field's clause : 'select key,
ingredient from articleingredient'. I want to get the field 'ingredient' which is stored as RTF strings in plain text format. Is there a UDF or stored procedure to convert the rtf format to plain text?

Comment: You either need to write it yourself (in which case this question is probably too broad), or you need/want to find a UDF/stored procedure (in which case this question is off topic). In any case, Firebird doesn't have built-in support.