# Convert an RTF database field in Firebird to string

Tags: delphi, firebird, rtf, richtext

I am creating a new application and I need to reuse data from the old one. The old one using Firebird as database and Delphi.

The problem is, inside the Firebird database there is a column which contains strange characters. For example:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial
Narrow;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans
Serif;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\f0\fs18 11.0 - 16.5\f1\fs16\par}
```

in the application it is displayed as

> 11.0 - 16.5

and

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Arial
Narrow;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 MS Sans
Serif;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\lang1033\f0\fs18 3.500 -
10.000\f1\fs16\par}
```

in application it is displayed as

> 3.500 - 10.000

I do not know why the previous developer store the data this way,

How can I pick the string / character that I need, without manually editing the database?

Comment: It is the so called RTF format. You can read it as string and load e.g. to a `TRichEdit` control and read it as plain text, but to get just the value you will need a parser.

Comment: There is also the data aware [TDBRichEdit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/Vcl.DBCtrls.TDBRichEdit)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188545/regular-expression-for-extracting-text-from-an-rtf-string

Comment: @TLama ,your answer is good, but it would be better if you include rtf format to plain text. ill happy to give mark on your answer^^

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595865/get-plain-text-from-an-rtf-text, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841579/how-to-extract-plain-text-from-rtf-string-using-firebird-sql, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227899/using-trichedit-at-runtime-without-defining-a-parent, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3214281/delphi-best-way-to-convert-rtf-to-text